# Most efficient way to split a string on the first occurrence of a digit ?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, list, char

```
JamesBond001.txt
JamesBond002.txt
JamesBond003.txt
```

I want to split this into two parts {JamesBond|001} ,{JamesBond|002},{JamesBond|003}

Comment: anything you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I split the string into an array and then checked if it was a digit or a character. And then inserted it into an array.

Comment: @Paul It did but there's thousand of files in the directory and I'm wondering what the most efficient way to do this is.

Comment: No need to split into an array. Iterate over the string and look for a digit?. Then substring to get the bits. It's going to be as quick as anything else. A regexp will be slower for sure.

Comment: @vks `(?<=\D)(?=\d)` is both simpler and more correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow you to reach an informed decision, here's a benchmark for the two competing solutions.

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OperationsPerInvocation(Measure.SIZE)
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 100, timeUnit=MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1000, timeUnit=MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Threads(1)
@Fork(1)
public class Measure
{
  public static final int SIZE = 1;

  String toSplit;

  @Setup public void setup() {
    final Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    toSplit = IntStream.range(0, 100)
        .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char)(i < 95? 'A'+rnd.nextInt(20) : '0'+rnd.nextInt(10))))
        .collect(joining());
  }

  static final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");

  @Benchmark public String[] regex() {
    return regex.split(toSplit);
  }

  @Benchmark public String[] loop() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < toSplit.length(); i++)
      if (toSplit.charAt(i) >= '0' && toSplit.charAt(i) <= '9')
        break;
    return new String[] { toSplit.substring(0, i), toSplit.substring(i, toSplit.length()) };
  }
}
```

So we're testing with a 100-char string where the last 5 chars are digits. That's about the worst case because we have to search through almost the whole longish string to find the split point.

Results:

```
Benchmark            Mode  Samples     Score      Error  Units
o.s.Measure.loop     avgt        5    96,772 ±    8,671  ns/op
o.s.Measure.regex    avgt        5  3720,446 ± 1096,872  ns/op
```

The custom loop beats the regex into the ground, even though we were careful enough to compile the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compact one that may take advantage of any special efficiencies of `String.indexof`. I'd be interested in it's efficiency.

```
public static int indexAnyOf(String of, String in) {
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        if (of.indexOf(in.charAt(i)) != -1) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public void test() {
    String agent = "JamesBond007.txt";
    int firstDigit = indexAnyOf("0123456789", agent);
    System.out.println(agent.substring(0, firstDigit) + "|" + agent.substring(firstDigit));
}
```

Comment: You're four times slower than my "loop". That's probably because you have  O(n^2) complexity in there. Well, not exactly O(n^2), but you do check every char against each individual digit instead of exploiting their arithmetical grouping.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Thanks Marko - I was wondering if perhaps there was some kind of `rep scasb` functionality compiled into `indexOf` which would make this nearly `O(n)` but clearly not.

Comment: I was wondering about something similar, too :) But `rep scasb` would only be able to take out some constant factor from `indexOf`---it would still need to scan the whole "digits" string for each char. This is avoided if you just do two simple size comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\D)(?=\d)
```

Try this.Replace by `\n`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/63

Comment: OP wants efficient. That's not going to be the fastest. There's an argument this is the wrong thing to worry about optimizing, though!

Comment: For a mere thousand files there is really no point in optimizing. In my benchmark, splitting one long string (100 chars) takes under 4 µs with a regex. You'll never notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
    String agent = "JamesBond001.txt";
    int len = agent.length();
    String left = null, right = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(agent.charAt(i))) {
            left = agent.substring(0, i);
            right = agent.substring(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

but probably you're optimising in the wrong place. Write the code so it's clear, simple and works, then measure where the time is really going. I'll bet it's not mostly in this part of your app!